# V-model with props & computed properties

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a checkbox component that tracks whether or not an item has been saved by the user as a favorite. This information is passed in as a prop.

Because we can't/shouldn't mutate props passed in from a parent component, I am using v-model on a computed property.

```
<template>
  <input class="favorite" type="checkbox" v-model="checked">
</template>
<script>
  module.exports = {
    props: ['favorite'],
    computed: {
      checked: {
        get: function getChecked() {
          return this.favorite;
        },
        set: function setChecked(newVal) {
          this.$emit('update:favorite', newVal);
        }
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

The parent component controls sending requests to the favorites api & updating the state of each entity if/when the request is successful.

```
<template>
  <input-favorite
    @update:favorite="toggleFavorite" 
    :favorite="entity.favorite"
  ></input-favorite>
</template>
<script>
  module.exports = {
    methods: {
      toggleFavorite: function toggleFavorite(val) {
        if (val) {
          this.$store.dispatch('postFavorite', { id: this.entity.id, name: this.entity.name });
        } else {
          this.$store.dispatch('deleteFavorite', this.entity.id);
        }
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

If the request fails, however, is it possible to prevent the checkbox from getting checked in the first place?  Both `this.favorite` and `this.checked` stay in sync, but the state of the checkbox does not.

Because the data & props stay correct, I'm also having trouble figuring out how I could trigger a re-render of the checkbox to get it back to the correct state.

Comment: Note: your component doesn't accept `entity` as a prop, though you are passing it. Setting the checkbox value should just be a matter of setting `entity.favorite` appropriately when you detect that a request has failed.

Comment: Typo in the question, not in the actual component. My apologies. `entity.favorite` is always correct.  It starts out as `entity.favorite = false`. Even though the computed prop `checked` and the prop `favorite` (passed in from `entity.favorite` do not change, the checkbox is checked and I cannot reset it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that `favorite` never changes, so Vue doesn't see a need to update. You should update it to `true` upon receiving the checked value (so state is consistent) and then update it again to `false` when the request fails.

```js
Vue.component('inputFavorite', {
  template: '#input-favorite',
  props: ['favorite'],
  computed: {
    checked: {
      get: function getChecked() {
        return this.favorite;
      },
      set: function setChecked(newVal) {
        this.$emit('update:favorite', newVal);
      }
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    entity: {
      favorite: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleFavorite: function toggleFavorite(val) {
      if (val) {
        console.log("Post");
        this.entity.favorite = true;
        // Mock up a failure
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log("Failed");
          this.entity.favorite = false;
        }, 250);
      } else {
        console.log("Delete");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<template id="input-favorite">
  <input class="favorite" type="checkbox" v-model="checked">
</template>

<div id="app">
  <input-favorite @update:favorite="toggleFavorite" :favorite="entity.favorite"></input-favorite>
</div>
```

The way you have set this up lends itself to the recently-reintroduced [`.sync` modifier](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier), which would simplify your HTML a bit:

```
  <input-favorite :favorite.sync="entity.favorite"></input-favorite>
```

Then you do away with `toggleFavorite` and instead add a `watch`:

```
watch: {
  'entity.favorite': function (newValue) {
    console.log("Updated", newValue);
    if (newValue) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Failed");
        this.entity.favorite = false;
      }, 250);
    }
  }
}
```