# How set computed property of checked checkboxes via v-model?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I've looked several resources, but I don't find the solution:

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html
- [V-model with props & computed properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658945/v-model-with-props-computed-properties)
- [vuejs v-model, multiple checkbox and computed property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42248888/vuejs-v-model-multiple-checkbox-and-computed-property)

I've a table with people that have roles, if I want to change the roles I open a modal.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table small outlined striped hover :items="peoplePaginated.data" :fields="fields" >
      <template slot="actions" slot-scope="row">
        <b-button size="sm" class="my-2 my-sm-0 btn-outline-info" v-b-modal="'federation-role-modal'" @click.stop="change(row.item)">
        edit
        </b-button>
        <b-button size="sm" @click.stop="info(row.item, row.index, $event.target)" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">
          details
        </b-button>
      </template>
    </b-table>
    <FederationRoleModal :roles="roles" />
  </div>
</template>


data () {
 return {
    roles: [],
 }
},


  methods: {
    info (item) {
      this.$router.push({ name: 'person', params: { id: item.id }})
    },
    change (person) {
      const roles = person.personRoles.map(el => el)
      const allRoles = roles.map(el => el.roleCategory.name)
      this.roles = allRoles
    }
  }
```

Then I've a list of *checkboxes* where the `checkedRoles` takes care of the checked ones. When I click on a new checkbox, I want the data property to be updated. However this updating does not happen.

In the modal:

```
<span v-for="value in allRoles" :key="value.id">
    <input type="checkbox" :value="value" v-model="checkedRoles">
    <span class="checkbox-label"> {{value}} </span> <br>
</span>



computed property: {
  checkedRoles: {
    get: function () {
      // console.log(this.roles)
      return this.roles
    },
    set: function (newValue) {
      // console.log(newValue)
      return newValue
    }
  }
}
```

`this.roles` comes from the parent component (array with roles).
I do see the `console.log(newValue)` output as a new array with an additional role, but this new array is not visible as the `checkedRoles` data property.

- [option 2] I've also tried to add `checkedRoles: this.roles,` in the `data () { return {... }`. But when I open several times a modal, the roles of the previous clicked `row.item` are still in the data property.

Please advise

1. if I should be using a computed property, or dig deeper into [option 2]
2. how I get all checked checkboxes to be in the `checkedRoles` data property.

Comment: Not sure about the specifics of your implementation but here's a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ljs1b27/) to show you how this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution included modifying the parent component data property:

In the parent component add:

```
<FederationRoleModal :checked-roles="roles" @update-role="onUpdateRole"/>
```

methods:

```
    onUpdateRole(value) {
      let rolesArray = this.roles
      if (rolesArray.includes(value)){
        var index = rolesArray.indexOf(value)
        if (index > -1) {
          return rolesArray.splice(index, 1);
        }
      } else {
        return rolesArray.push(value)
      }
    }
```

in the child component

```
      <span v-for="value in allRoles" :key="value.id">
        <input type="checkbox" :value="value" v-model="roles" @click="$emit('update-role', value)">
        <span class="checkbox-label"> {{value}} </span> <br>
      </span>
```

data:

```
props: ['checkedRoles'],
```

computed:

```
roles: {
  get: function () {
   return this.checkedRoles
 },
 set: function (newValue) {
   return newValue
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`checkRoles` should be an empty array in your data object like :

```
   data(){
      return{
        checkedRoles:[]
        ...
       }
     }
```

---

```
     <span v-for="value in allRoles" :key="value.id">
       <input type="checkbox" :value="value" v-model="checkedRoles">
       <span class="checkbox-label"> {{value}} </span> <br>
     </span>
```

Comment: Correct. To be sure, the person could already have roles, so I want to assign those roles to the initiation of checkedRoles.

Comment: in this case you could emit the checkedroles to the parent component and override the person roles in the parent component via `this$emit` function

Comment: Supplied the solution in my answer below. It is indeed via `this.$emit`.